# How to get desktop or browser notifications for new questions?

Tags: feature-request

#### Has anyone been able to get desktop or browser notifications of new questions on mathematica.stackexchange.com?

I notice that whenever I post a question it immediately gets 1 view.

[image]

So maybe someone is getting a desktop notification of my question?

#### Things I tried:

- I downloaded the stackexchange app on my phone.
- I signed up for the email alerts - but these are up to 15 minutes late

note. I'm working on Ubuntu with a Chromium browser.

Comment: Probably you could build your own by accessing the [stackexchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) from Mathematica and pushing events with  `ServiceConnect["Pushbullet"]`?

Comment: @rhermans that is a good idea. I have added it to my list of future projects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'Viewed 1 time' is just your own view after posting the question. Those count towards the number of views too.

There's no official support for desktop or browser notification; coincidentally, the company [just declined a feature request to have web push notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321093/295232). To get real time notifications, you'd have to do some programming and hook up the [websockets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218343/295232) (which provide the '1 new question' banner on the homepage) to your own notification service. (I have done something like that; I get a push notification on my iPhone whenever a new Meta question is posted across the network. That's actually how I found this question ... but it takes a lot of work and doesn't scale. For starters, you'd need an [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/)).